# Include ASP.NET Header and Footer on PHP Website

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress blog for someone with an ASP.NET website, their hosting provider won't install PHP on their server so we're having to use an external Linux server.

My question is, is there a good way to include their ASP.NET header and footer into the Wordpress blog despite it being hosted externally on Linux server.

Thanks.

Comment: get the generated contents of the files header and footer using file_get_contents http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php and put the php code in the wordpress template files header.php and footer.php

Comment: It depends on what you exactly mean by header and footer: are they just images or nested div's with their own css etc.? If they are images, you can just reference them as if they were a local resource.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the header and footer are ASP controls of some form, and assuming those controls are likely to includes things like links and images with relative urls, the easiest solution would be to create a simple ASP page with the header and footer controls, and in the middle an iframe pointing to the server hosting the blog.

The other option would be to create two "hidden" ASP pages that contain the header and footer controls. Then your wordpress code could use something like `file_get_contents` to get the contents of those pages, and the [PHP DOM API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse out the parts you need and rewrite any relative urls.